# From equivalent graphs to isomorphic one- Reconstruction Conjecture

Tags: graph-theory, graph-reconstruction

Suppose we are working with connected simple graphs.

We say the graph $G$ and $H$ are equivalent if for any spanning tree $T_G$ in $G$ there is an spanning tree $T_H$ in $H$ such that $T_G$ is isomorphic to $T_H$ and vice versa.

Can we say that if $G$ and $H$ are equivalent, then they are isomorphic?

The motivation of this question goes back to the reconstruction conjecture. I want to say that if  $G$ and $H$ are equivalent and RC is true for one of these graphs, then it is true for other one.

Comment: Based on its [MR review](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=412046), Sedláček - The reconstruction of a graph from its spanning trees says no; but I can't find the original article.

Comment: @LSpice The article is [here](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/126560/MathSlov_24-1974-4_3.pdf).

Comment: @LSpice: thanks for the reference. I saw the paper quickly. I do not want to construct the graphs by its spanning trees. I want to say if $G$ and $H$ are equivalent and $G$ is RC, then $H$ is RC.

Comment: Your question seems to ask whether two equivalent-in-your-sense graphs are isomorphic, and the answer (by Sedláček's [article](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/126560/MathSlov_24-1974-4_3.pdf)) is that they need not be.

Comment: @bof: you are right, and I have to change the word "equivalent ". But, if I have one of them, I am done. Since $P_4$ is ... to $K_4$ and RC is true for $P_4$, then it is true for other one.

Comment: @LSpice: you are right. Thanks for example. Actually, it is a good news.

Comment: While @bof's comments on terminology are certainly apposite, surely this isn't what you meant.  If you really wanted this asymmetric relation, then it is easy to come up with counterexamples:  just take $H$ a non-tree, and $G$ a spanning tree of $H$.  Surely what you meant was to consider the case where each spanning tree of $G$ is isomorphic to a spanning tree of $H$, *and vice versa* (possibly with multiplicity)?  Anyway, the [counterexample of Sedláček](https://mathoverflow.net/a/380808) is a counterexample to this stronger condition.

Comment: a cycle is equivalent to a path with the same number of vertices

Comment: @FedorPetrov, [indeed](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/380804) according to the current definition (it has been changing), so I think that's why one probably also wants to include something about [multiplicity of spanning trees](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/380804).  The graphs in the [counterexample of Sedláček](https://mathoverflow.net/a/380808) satisfy this stronger notion of equivalence, but still are not isomorphic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following counterexample, with two finite, connected graphs in which every tree occurs as a spanning tree with the same multiplicity but that are not isomorphic, is given in [Sedláček - The reconstruction of a graph from its spanning trees](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/126560/MathSlov_24-1974-4_3.pdf) (thanks to @JeremyRickard for the [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380804/from-equivalent-graphs-to-isomorphic-one-reconstruction-conjecture#comment967435_380804)):
[image: Two graphs that are 'equivalent' but not isomorphic]